# How to add external class source folder in java project through eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, import

I have a project in java and I am working in eclipse.

My question is whether there is a way to import the contents of a jar file (which contains the java files also) into a project so that the java files are editable?

I can unzip the jar file into a folder which will have the subfolders of the projects as shown inside the jar file. I have tried to inform the project via *Add External Class Folder* in *Java Build Path* but I don't see any changes in the tree folder. I cannot pick it as an option when correcting errors in eclipse.

Copying all files and structure in my scr folder is not an acceptable option (there are several files that all should be updated of the package change etc).

So how do I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

I would unzip the jar file into a *separate eclipse project*, created for the purpose rather than a folder, which, don't forget doesn't have to be anywhere near your default workspace location. 
[image]

Then I'd use the *Required projects on build path* option to point from your original project to your jarWrapper. 
[image]